# Carto trying to set syncing with a PostGIS database connection

Tags: postgis, carto, api, connection

I'm trying to set up a syncing connection between Carto and a PostGIS Table. However, I'm not seeing updates in Carto, and the table does not show up in my list of syncs when I make a Get request.

This is the code I'm using to set it up

```
curl.exe -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\"connector\": {
 \"provider\": \"postgres\",
 \"connection\": {
   \"server\":\"[SERVERURL]\",
   \"database\":\"[DBNAME]\",
   \"username\":\"[USERNAME]\",
   \"password\":\"[PWD]\"
 },
 \"schema\": \"[SCHEMA]\",
 \"table\": \"[TABLE]\"},   \"interval\": 3600}' "https://[DOMAIN].carto.com/api/v1/imports/?api_key=[APIKEY]"
```

The response I get is

> "item_queue_id":"[QUEUEID]","success":true}* Connection #0 to host [DOMAIN].carto.com left intact

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: use /api/v1/synchronizations  rather than imports? https://carto.com/developers/import-api/guides/sync-tables/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will that apply? I've been able to use that guide you linked for syncing files, but what I need is to sync a georeferenced table from Postgis.
I'm following the steps from this entry in the same reference guide: https://carto.com/developers/import-api/guides/database-connectors/#the-postgresql-connector